# Sails.js: save() model doesn't seems to work Error (E_UNKNOWN)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

My model definition looks like this:

```
//api/models/Table.js
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'table',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            size: 11
        },
        title1: {
            type: 'string',
            index: true,
            size: 255
        },
        title2: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 255
        },
        title2: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 255
        },
        countries: { //Countries nationalities
            model: 'hg_laender'
        },
        year: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 4
        },
        relased: { //released
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['true', 'false']
        },
        createdOn: { //Created on
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        changedOn: { // Changed on
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        documents: { //Document type
            collection: 'documents',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        creator: { //Creator
            collection: 'creator',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        kanton: { // Canton
            collection: 'kanton',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        language: {
            collection: 'language',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        }
    }
};
```

The code generating the error is the following

```
    Table.find()
    .exec((err, tables) => {
        if(err) {
            sails.log.error('first error', err);
        }
        sails.log.debug(tables[0]); //The record is loaded correctly
        tables[0].save((err, model) => {
            if(err) {
                sails.log.error('second error', err);
            }
        });
    });
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: second error Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
    at new WLError (/home/xxx/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/error/WLError.js:25:15)
    at /home/xxx/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/model/lib/defaultMethods/save.js:196:17
    at /home/xxx/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /home/xxx/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:550:17
    at /home/xxx/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:544:17
    at _arrayEach (/home/xxx/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
    at Immediate.taskComplete (/home/xxx/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:543:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

If a use the `create()` method it works. t actually save the record on the database. But if I try to update it, it doesn't work.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Additional info:
- sails.js version: 0.12.8

Comment: Which version of sails are you using? `.save` method provides only a single argument `err`. `.save(err, updatedModel)` method is now deprecated.

Comment: @MjZac I use version `0.12.8` of sails.js. I tried to use a function with a single argument but i get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was a problem if a manually specify the id of the model.
Now i changed the model like below and it works. Btw I don't know why specifing the id will not work. Also it' doesn't throw any error when creating a model..

```
//api/models/Table.js
module.exports = {
    tableName: 'table',
    autoCreatedAt: false,
    autoUpdatedAt: false,
    attributes: {
        //id: {
        //    type: 'integer',
        //    autoIncrement: true,
        //    primaryKey: true,
        //    size: 11
        //},
        title1: {
            type: 'string',
            index: true,
            size: 255
        },
        title2: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 255
        },
        title2: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 255
        },
        countries: { //Countries nationalities
            model: 'hg_laender'
        },
        year: {
            type: 'string',
            size: 4
        },
        relased: { //released
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['true', 'false']
        },
        createdOn: { //Created on
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        changedOn: { // Changed on
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        documents: { //Document type
            collection: 'documents',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        creator: { //Creator
            collection: 'creator',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        kanton: { // Canton
            collection: 'kanton',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        },
        language: {
            collection: 'language',
            via: 'table',
            dominant: true
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have autoPK set to false in your model configuration?

Comment: No, didn't know that was necessary

Comment: Default autoPK is default set to true (even though its not specified anywhere); to manually assign a primary key you have to set it to false; see [the documentation under Primary Key](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#unique)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this Issue while using Sails with mongo. I fixed this by changing "id" attribute to some other attribute, say "Id". While creating a record, an "id" attribute is created itself that holds mongo ObjectId. May be this could be the reason for not allowing two id attribute at the same time resulting into error.